# Exporting from Altium to CST PCB Studio

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium

Based on [CST website](https://www.cst.com/Products/CSTPCBS/ImpExp), they claim that CST PCB Studio can import Altium files.

But when I open Import on CST , it gives me just these options :

[image: CST PCB Studio Import]

I tried to Export Altium to HyperLynx and Import it to CST PCB Studio,but it gave error too.
I also tried converting to AutoCAD and use ODB++ , but still gives error for importing.

I'm using CST Suite Studio,Release version 2014.00 - Feb 24 2014

Do you have any solution ?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the latest CST? It could be a new facility.

Comment: I'm using CST Suite Studio,Release version 2014.00 - Feb 24 2014.

Comment: Altium isn't an option! Try using something else.

Comment: I found the solution,

In Altium , I went to **File > Fibraction Outputs > ODB++** and exported in this way.

Now it can easily imported via CST.

Comment: @LeonHeller - You should tell that to all the places I consult for. I think they'd disagree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution,

In Altium , I went to **File > Fibraction Outputs > ODB++** and exported in this way.

Now it can easily imported via CST.

Comment: I confirm that ODB++ is the best option when you have to export a design from a PCB layout tool and use it on a EM simulator or SI tool.